# check if interface eth0 is up (configured)

Tags: linux, networking

I need to check with a script, whether `eth0` is configured. If so, the script will do nothing. Otherwise it will start `wlan0`. (I don't want both `eth0` and `wlan0` to be up at the same time).

What would be the easiest way to check, whether `eth0` is already up?

I am using Debian Wheezy

## CLARIFICATION:

I would like to check not only that the cable in `eth0` is plugged in, but rather that the interface is configured (i.e. it has either static IP set, or it has received a DHCP IP). If cable is plugged in, but `eth0` is not configured correctly, I want to start `wlan0`

Comment: I'm not sure about what I'm going to say but `cat /sys/class/net/ | grep eth0` should give you easilly parsable data. You could also do `sudo ethtool eth0 | grep Link`

Comment: Pretty related: [How to check the physical status of an ethernet port in Linux?](http://serverfault.com/q/15776/200076)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can do it many ways. Here an example:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate
up
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't guarantee that the interface is fully configured. You can cat `/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier`, to check for a signal, but it still may not have a DHCP lease yet, etc.

Comment: In addition to this comment, several other answers here have gotten comments to the effect: `This doesn't work.` While it's useful knowing that this answer may not work in all instances, it would be much more helpful if the commentor: `1.)` gave a reference, cited an example or explained how to correct the exception, or `2.)` submitted an answer that covers the exception.

Answer (score 12):

```
ip a show ethX up
```

If nothing displayed then your interface is down

Comment: This method: "ip a show ethX up" and check for output, is not sufficient

Comment: @JoshuaClayton It would be nice if you could elaborate, because for me it works.

Comment: I can't remember for the world what didn't work about this for me back then. It does seem to always print something, UP or DOWN, but thats easily parsed by human or machine.

Comment: I see no different in output with or without `up` (e.g. `ip a show wlan0` and `ip a show wlan0 up` produce identical output on my machine). The other answers all `grep` for `state UP`; is there something extra needed to make the `up` argument work?

Answer (score 6):

```
ip a | grep -Eq ': eth0:.*state UP' || _do_your_thing
```

So here we *`grep`* the ubiquitous *[`ip`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip)* tool's *`stdout`* for a line which contains both our interface of interest and the phrase ***"state UP"*** ( thanks to @Lekensteyn for pointing out the need for a little more specificity than just *`UP`).* We use the argument *`a`* as the short form for *`address`* and that should be enough to get a listing of all configured network cards in system.

One advantage to using *`ip`* could be that it really should be available everywhere - it is how I commonly configure my Android phone's network devices, for instance.

The *`:colons`* are used to avoid partial matches - in this way we guarantee a match for *`eth0`* as opposed to an otherwise possible *`someothereth0`* or *`eth007`.*

Thanks @RaphaelAhrens for nudging me toward correctness and explaining my solution.

#### EDIT:

To handle the current requirements you could:

```
ip a | sed -rn '/: '"$if"':.*state UP/{N;N;s/.*inet (\S*).*/\1/p}'
```

The above will only print a CIDR ip address if your target *`$if`* is ***UP,*** plugged in, and has one. For ipv6 the solution is just as simple with only minor modification.

If you don't like *`sed`* you could achieve similar results with another *`|pipe ... grep`* and adding a *`-A`* context option to the first *`grep`* - but I like *`sed`.*

Comment: You should explain what you are doing. So that everyone can benefit from your answer.

Comment: This is insufficient. The output also contains `UP` if the device is up, but no cable is connected: `2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000`. You can also specify the device to avoid false positives: `ip addr show dev eth0`.

Comment: On an embedded linux 2.6 I get state UNKNOWN for all operable interfaces

Answer (score 0):

The other methods do not work, but this one does (on Ubuntu at least):

```
while true; do
    ip route | grep "linkdown"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        sleep 1  # network not yet up
    else
        break   # network up
    fi
done
```

Comment: There is no "linkdown" to grep with `ip route` on Debian Stretch.

Comment: Debian stretch here: if you configured a post-down to `ip route del default dev NICNAME` then `linkdown` will definitely will be shown.