# post-up and post-down ufw equivalent

Tags: iptables, ufw

Typically the `/etc/network/interfaces` file on Debian can include routing requirements such as

```
post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

If i wanted to exclusively use UFW (and not touch the interfaces file) where would I put the post-down line?

I know that the post-up line equivalent can be put inside `/etc/ufw/before.rules` like so:

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended but you can edit the function stop/restart on `/lib/ufw/ufw-init`
otherwise you can start a watching script with `/etc/ufw/after.init` that would fire your post-down when the interface is down... [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121523/check-if-interface-eth0-is-up-configured) may be helpful to write the watching script.

[More info](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ufw-framework.8.html)

Comment: Thank you, and welcome to StackExchange. I may resort to iptables and ditch UFW!